# Find The Maximum Of $|z^2-3z+2|$ at $|z|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value, maxima-minima

> Find the maximum points of $|z^2-3z+2|$ at $|z|\leq 1$

Because $z^2-3z+2$ the function is analytic on the interior of $|z|\leq 1$ the maximum will be obtained on the boundary.

Let $z=e^{it}$ where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

So the function is $e^{2it}-3e^{it}+2$ now I want to look at the boundry so I should take $|e^{2it}|-3|e^{it}|+2$?

Comment: Maximum of what? The magnitude of the expression, $|z^2-3z+2|$? Note the expression itself is complex, so "maximum" doesn't make sense applied to it alone. You have to be talking about some real number, so I'm guessing the magnitude of the expression (?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum of $z^2-3z+2$ is not defined because $z^2-3z+2\in\mathbb C$.

By the way,
$$|z^2-3z+2|\leq|z|^2+3|z|+2\leq6.$$
The equality occurs for $z=-1$.

Comment: You are of course correct, but it's (obviously) not what was intended to be asked, so maybe give the asker a chance for an edit?

Comment: Rozenberg, How did you find? $|z|^2+3|z|+2.$

Comment: @MathLife It's the triangle inequality: $|z^2-3z+2|\leq|z^2|+|-3z|+|2|=|z|^2+3|z|+2$

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the maximum of $\lvert z^2-3z+2\rvert=\lvert z-1\rvert\lvert z-2\rvert$, on the closed unit disc, a simple sketch will convince you the maximum of each factor is attained at $z=-1$, so the maximum of their product is attained at the same point, and it's equal to $6$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If you mean the maximum *magnitude* of that expression, then you want to find $t$ maximizing $$f(t)=|e^{2it}-3e^{it}+2|^2$$
$$=|(\cos 2t-3\cos t+2)+i(\sin 2t-3\sin t)|^2$$
$$=(\cos 2t-3\cos t+2)^2 + (\sin 2t-3\sin t)^2$$
(note that it is enough to maximize the *square* of the magnitude; that's convenient for getting rid of the pesky square root).

**Addendum:** It's easy to differentiate $f$ and factor the result to get
$$f'(t) = 8(\sin t)(\cos t - \tfrac32)(\cos ^2 t - \tfrac32)$$

Since both of the last two factors are strictly negative for all $t$, this vanishes precisely when $\sin t$ vanishes, i.e., when $t=k\pi$ for integral $k$. You can check that
$$f(k\pi)=\begin{cases}
=0, & k \textrm{ even} & \textrm{(so } z = e^{k\pi i}= 1\textrm{)}\\
=36, & k \textrm{ odd} & \textrm{(so } z = e^{k\pi i}= -1\textrm{)}
\end{cases}$$

Thus the magnitude of your original expression is minimized (with value $0$) at $z=1$, and is maximized (with value $6$) at $z=-1$.

Comment: This is exactly what OP has asked for. +1

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very simple.Look:

$$|z^2-3z+2|=|(z-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}|$$

We can write $$-1≤z≤1$$
$$-\frac{5}{2}≤z-\frac{3}{2}≤-\frac{1}
{2}$$

Finally,

$$\frac{25}{4}≥(z-\frac{3}{2})^2≥\frac{1}{4}$$

$$6≥(z-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}≥0$$

$$6≥|(z-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}|≥0$$

$$f(z)_{max}=6, |z|≤1$$

Done.

Comment: $z$ is a complex number, we can't use inequality with a complex number!

Comment: Order is not defined for $\mathbb{C}$